# How to add hypens to a string (to format it like a 16-digit serial number)

Tags: javascript

I have folling javascript to generate random 20 digits . I need to append hypen after every 5th digit to make like serial number format like given example

e.g. DF347-VB895-98AP8-34NQ2

```js
function randomString() {
 var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZ";
 var string_length = 20;
 var randomstring = '';
 for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
  var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
  randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
 }
 document.write(randomstring);
}
```

```html
<body onload="randomString();">
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, please label it.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a hyphen every 5th iteration:

```js
function randomString() {
 var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZ";
 var string_length = 20;
 var randomstring = '';
 for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
       if (i !== 0 && i%5 === 0) {
          randomstring += '-';
       }
    randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
 }
 document.write(randomstring);
}
```

```html
<body onload="randomString();">
```

Comment: Oh God, no! Just place the if condition before adding the substring, and do `if (i !== 0 && i%5 === 0)`

Comment: @adeneo thanks, I knew something was wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `match` to break it into pieces and `join` to rebuild it with hyphens, like this:

```
var randomstring = 'DF347VB89598AP834NQ2',
    withHyphens = randomstring
                    .match(/.{5}/g) // breaks it into 5-character strings
                    .join('-'); // rebuilds it with hyphen separators
alert(withHyphens); // DF347-VB895-98AP8-34NQ2
```

Or, as Hunter McMillen suggests, since you're building the string on the fly, just add a hyphen every 5th time through the loop.

You also indicated in an answer (side note: this should be an edit to your question, not an edit) that you need to append `-XXXXX`. Just do one of the above methods, then

```
withHyphens += '-XXXXX';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression replace:

```
randomstring = randomstring.replace(/.{5}(?!$)/g, '$&-');
```

The negative lookahead `(?!$)` prevents it from adding a hyphen at the end.

Comment: or you could use `(?!$)`

Comment: Thanks, I like that better.

Comment: Nice answer, but do people actually enjoy using comicbook-cursewords to do their bidding? I personally would use @HunterMcMillen answer, if another human being should be able read the code.

Comment: Agreed. If you're already adding characters in a loop, it's easy to add the hyphen at the same time. My solution is useful if you have to add hyphens to an existing string.

Comment: @supertopi - Did noone notice that Hunter's answer produce the wrong result and is actually more complicated than the other answers, or is it just me ?

Comment: More complicated how? And I didnt notice the off by one. Oops.

Comment: You have to add the hyphen before the substring, and using a condition and a modulus in every iteration isn't really simpler than just splitting and joining the finished string in my opinion, but maybe it's easier to read ?

Comment: Even doing the modulus every iteration will be more efficient than building the string, then building a new one. My update makes it slightly more complex to read though; so now I don't know which solution I like better

Answer (score 0):

How about using substring to break up your 20 digit number string? **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1btznfoy/)**

```
var randnum = "12345678910111213145";
var serial = randnum.substring(0,4) + "-" + randnum.substring(5,9) + "-" + randnum.substring(10,14) + "-" + randnum.substring(15,19);
```